# Unable to log in

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement

hi i am building a social network with Laravel  but even though i log in it always says that the password is wrong but it is correct i think the problem is in the following part of code,
 please show me the error?

```
 public function getsignin()
 {
     return view('auth.signin');
 }

 public function postsignin(Request $request)
 {
     $this->validate($request, [
        'email'=>'required',
        'password'=>'required'
     ]);

     if( !Auth::attempt($request->only(['email','password']), $request->has('remember'))) {
         return redirect()->back()->with('info','Whoops! Try again please...');
     }

     return redirect()->route('home')->with('info','Welcome!');
}
```

Comment: When you stored your passwords, did you Hash them?

Comment: yes of course @EddyTheDove

Comment: What is the exact error message that you're seeing here? Are you being redirected back with the "Whoops! Try again please..." message? If there's any other error, this could be caused by any one of a large number of issues, for example:

1. Is your route registered correctly?
2. Is your request failing validation for any reason?
3. Is Auth being included in the file?
4. Are the email and password parameters being passed to the attempt() method in the correct format?
5. Does the email being used for signing in match up against the email in the database?

Comment: How do you know the password is wrong? It returns 'Whoosp...' ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to name your parameters like this:

```
if( !Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->has('remember'))) {
     ...
 }
```

Comment: your code gives this                                                              FatalErrorException in AuthController.php line 43:
syntax error, unexpected ',' @EddyTheDove

Comment: Oh yes, I closed a bracked after `$request->password`. I shouldn'[t close the bracket there. Check the update.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password, $request->has('remember'))]) {
     ...
 }
```

When attempting, your parameter must be one array, with key=>value pairs of attributes you want to be accepted